# How did Odysseus's ship get wrecked, and how did Odysseus himself land to Ogygia?

Tags: greek, odyssey, homer

I have tried to read Homer's *Odyssey* and commentaries to find out details about how Odysseus's shipwreck happened, how many men were involved and saved and so forth. It looks like the first book starts when Odysseus was already in the Ogygia island, and information is scattered to several books. Is there a good summary giving this kind of information about this famous story?

Comment: Always assumed it was a god's intervention

Comment: I don't remember if this is explicitly mentioned anywhere, but I think it was Poseidon's doing as you find out he doesn't like Odysseus.

Comment: Plus, he crashed the raft.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is detailed in book 12 of the Odyssey. Odysseus' crew disobeyed his (and the gods') command not to eat the cattle of Helios, which led to Helios' and Zeus' displeasure. So Zeus sends a storm destroying the survivors, as they had just made it through Scylla and Charybdis. Odysseus is swept back to the latter, and sort of just floats on to Ogygia.

You can read the passage yourself on [Theoi](http://www.theoi.com/Text/HomerOdyssey12.html). Start from line 374.

Comment: The poem's invocation calls the last surviving companions of Odysseus fools (νήπιοι) for eating those kine, but it seems unjust to blame them; it is part of the gods' plan, as pronounced by Poseidon (9.528-35) and acknowledged as fate by Odysseus himself (11.139). Both Odysseus' sleep (12.339) and the flat impossibility of launching the single remaining ship against a persistent adverse wind (12.313-15) are explicitly said to be the gods' doing, and Eurylochos' preference for drowning (or whatever) later over starvation now is at least rational (12.342-43).

Comment: So all men died on home return except Odysseus. But it is not explicitly stated how many were there when the adventure started? Could we count all the lost men from the storyline?

Comment: @MarkokraM Unfortunately not.

Answer (score -3):

I think you must start with the [Catalog of Ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalogue_of_Ships) from the Iliad, take the number of sailors from Odysseus's group, and start with adventure against [Cicones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicones). Also, don't forget the story about [Lestrigones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lestrigones)--there is a heavy loss  for Odysseus.

See: 
[Iliad Book II](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0134%3Abook%3D2%3Acard%3D1) 
[Odyssey Book IX](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0136%3Abook%3D9%3Acard%3D1) 
[Odyssey Book X](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0136%3Abook%3D10%3Acard%3D178)